# Recommended ways of hiding an HTML element as a temporary bot prevention method

Tags: html, css, forms

Let's say that I have some marginal trouble with bots and automated form submission. Further, let's assume that the usual visitors of my site are people who are not skilled with captchas or anything of the sort.

I've thought about placing a non-visible HTML input element (several, actually, peppered about the form), and ignoring all submissions which have that field filled.

I'm trying to avoid going with the usual `type="hidden"` or `display:none` or `visibility:hidden` attributes.

So far, I've come up with this:

```
.myClass {
    position: absolute;
    top: -50%;
    left: -50%;
    filter: opacity(0);
}
```

Are there any other ways you can think of, which would make an element effectively invisible to the common user / site visitor?

Cross-browser compatibility would be nice.

**EDIT**: Using Google's reCaptcha v3 is not applicable, since the vast majority of users comes to the link directly, fills out the form, and has little to none interaction with the rest of the site.

Comment: DId you know about https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/v3? Its a recaptcha without any user interact

Comment: @Roy Yes, but unfortunately, it's not applicable in this case, since the vast majority of users comes to the link directly, fills out the form, and that's it. Will mention that in the original question.

Comment: Search for `honeypot`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think of

```
  transform: scale(0);
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
```

Comment: @LGSon Who says its OT?

Comment: Which of the reasons on that page do you consider to match this case? I can't find any. And by now, you are the only one who voted to close.

Comment: Yes, indeed, I do!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191078/discussion-between-yunzen-and-lgson).

Comment: You can't impose your opinion on the community. If this post would be OT or to broad, the community would have closed it by now.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. As it turns out, the bots were only filling out the required fields, so my attempts turned out to be futile.

Comment: You should consider a time measurement on filling out the form. Capture the submit event of the form and add the time to the form which has gone by since the losing of the page (or form, if it is inserted via JavaScript/Ajax). If this value is missing or less then, say, two seconds you should value the form submission as spam.

Comment: That's an interesting way of going about it. I'll try it out, thanks.